# Wait for song played outside of python to finish

Tags: python, linux, mp3, subprocess, python-3.4

I am trying to wait for a song to finish to play the next song.

I am running python 3.4 on windows but am trying to be able to use it on Linux (`raspberry pi`).

I have used the command `subprocess.call([PLAYER, SONG])` to open the mp3 file. It plays in vlc and then stops. I know that I have not incorporated anything for the program to tell python when its finished.

That's where you guys come in. I want to find a command that will wait until the song has finished and when the song is finished, the rest of the code will process.

I would like the command to be able to used on a Linux operating system and I am trying not to have to install any modules.

If modules are definitely needed, I will install them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [VLC python bindings](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings) to get the different information about the VLC player.

There are different methods that can provide your different information. You may achieve your solution by using the  [get_state(self)](http://liris.cnrs.fr/advene//download/python-ctypes/doc/) method, it provides the state information of the player. So, when the song is completed the VLC state would be stopped.

Sample code:

```
import vlc

def setup_player(filename):
    vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
    media = vlc_instance.media_new(filename)
    player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()# Start the player
    print player.get_state()# Print player's state
    player.stop()# Stop the player
    print player.get_state()# Print player's state

setup_player('filename')#Put media file name/location here
```

I hope it was helpful.